# Issue while extracting sub-strings with or without intervening space and punctuation?

Tags: r, regex-lookarounds, stringr

I am trying to extract the words "Present", "Retained" or "Absent" from text strings with variable formatting of spaces and punctuation using str_extract for a given pattern. Where am I off with the logic?

```
test<-c("as follows: ABC Staining Present in Tissue","ABC: Retained in the tumor cells      ","as follows: ABC Staining is Absent ABC","as follows: ABC Staining is missing in Tissue","as follows: ABC:   StainingAbsent in Tissue","as follows: ABC:   Staining Present in Tissue","as follows ABC Staining Present ABC")
pattern<-"ABC[:\\s]*[STAINING\\s]*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\bIN|ABC\\b)"
str_match(toupper(test), pattern)[,2]
```

Comment: But `ABC: Retained in the tumor cells` has neither `Present` nor `Absent`. It is not clear now what your requirements are.

Comment: Good point - Retained is a synonym for present in this case - entry edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `stringr::str_match`:

```
test<-c("as follows: ABC Staining Absent in Tissue","as follows: ABC:   StainingPresent in Tissue","as follows: ABC:   Staining Present in Tissue","as follows ABC Staining Present in Tissue extra words here in Present")

library(stringr)
pattern<-"ABC[:\\s]*Staining[:\\s]*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\bin\\b)"
unique(str_match(test, pattern)[,2])
## => [1] "Absent"  "Present"
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##lZDBCoJAEIbvPsWwp13RDh2lkOoFgrplxGpTLthaMyPV05uCBRUEXQZ@5puP4ae2FWSZxIVWluFQV1V95QRm8wWsxDrv/BFmOaMXcB7WjrlBFX2yCcALXxL@g8Nv/v2TLxbwJmThWtOeoUTCfjVQygRB5XKydNcs1N2TCc5WBMlPYtWJN0mW8TZ86oeoR2FqdDrtQphlufPdMCpovLs02Jt2JytFqfviIhiEZhONt6ZtHw) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSWgPU/1).

**Details**

- `ABC`  - `ABC` string
- `[:\s]*` - 0 or more colons or whitespaces
- `Staining` - a `Staining` string
- `[:\s]*` - 0 or more colons or whitespaces
- `(.*?)`  -Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\bin\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and then a whole word `in` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Wiktor - Love the approach. I'd like to loosen it a bit though in case: 1) Staining is missing, case issues, or "in" is missing. It's truncating the letter A from elements 3 and 5 now.

Comment: @sm002 Try `"(?i)ABC(?:[:\\s]+Staining)?(?:[\\s:]+is)?[\\s:]*(\\S+)"`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
str_extract(test, "(?<=Staining\\s{0,5})\\w+")
[1] "Absent"  "Present" "Present" "Present"
```

To address your question, where you're off with your logic. Your logic seems right, although it appears to me that you squeeze too much non-defining information into the pattern (e.g., it doesn't seem necessary to include `ABC` or the positive lookahead `(?=in)`). The major issue is of a *syntactic* nature. Look at the error you got: `Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)` The `*`quantifier matches zero or more times, that is, it is **not** of bounded length. Quantification with `{0,5}`(or any other number instead of `5`) **is** of bounded max length and is therefore admissible.